# How to display the contents of an Java Object on a Thymeleaf page

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I'm creating a payment page that integrates the Cielo E-commerce SDK, the controller looks like this:

```
public String result(@ModelAttribute CreditCard creditCard, @ModelAttribute Sale sale) {

        // Crie uma instância de Sale informando o ID do pagamento
        sale = new Sale("ID do pagamento");

        // Crie uma instância de Customer informando o nome do cliente
        Customer customer = sale.customer(creditCard.getHolder());

        // Crie uma instância de Payment informando o valor do pagamento
        Payment payment = new Payment(20000).setProvider(Provider.BancoDoBrasil).setType(Type.CreditCard);
        

        if (creditCard.isSaveCard()) {
            
            String correctDate = Formatter.formatExpirationDate(creditCard.getExpirationDate());
            
            creditCard = new CreditCard()
                        .setExpirationDate(correctDate)
                        .setBrand(creditCard.getBrand())
                        .setCardNumber(Formatter.formatCardNumber(creditCard.getCardNumber()))
                        .setHolder(creditCard.getHolder())
                        .setSecurityCode(creditCard.getSecurityCode()).setSaveCard(true);
            

            payment.setCreditCard(creditCard);

            sale.setPayment(payment);

            try {
                sale = new CieloEcommerce(merchant, Environment.SANDBOX).createSale(sale);

                CardTokenDatabase cardToken = new CardTokenDatabase();
                cardToken.setClientName(creditCard.getHolder());
                cardToken.setCardToken(sale.getPayment().getCreditCard().getCardToken());
                cardToken.setCardBrand(creditCard.getBrand());
                cardToken.setSecurityCode(creditCard.getSecurityCode());
                
                System.out.println(sale.getPayment().getReturnCode());
                
                payment = sale.getPayment();

                this.cardTokenService.save(cardToken);

                return resultPage(sale);
            } catch (CieloRequestException e) {
                CieloError error = e.getError();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        try {
            // Configure o SDK com seu merchant e o ambiente apropriado para criar a venda
            sale = new CieloEcommerce(merchant, Environment.SANDBOX).createSale(sale);

            String paymentId = sale.getPayment().getPaymentId();
        } catch (CieloRequestException e) {
            // Em caso de erros de integração, podemos tratar o erro aqui.
            // os códigos de erro estão todos disponíveis no manual de integração.
            CieloError error = e.getError();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        payment.setCreditCard(creditCard);

        sale.setPayment(payment);

        return "result";

    }
```

The returning response follows the format below:

```
{
    "MerchantOrderId": "ID do pagamento",
    "AcquirerOrderId": "202306121605391B664B",
    "Customer": {
        "Name": "Dr. Gregory Heathcote",
        "Address": {}
    },
    "Payment": {
        "ServiceTaxAmount": 0,
        "Installments": 1,
        "Interest": "ByMerchant",
        "Capture": false,
        "Authenticate": false,
        "Recurrent": false,
        "CreditCard": {
            "CardNumber": "453875******3829",
            "Holder": "Dr. Gregory Heathcote",
            "ExpirationDate": "09/2024",
            "Brand": "Visa"
        },
        "Tid": "0612040540131",
        "PaymentId": "48835b7d-e3af-45a2-9d85-2f7365415f5e",
        "Type": "CreditCard",
        "Amount": 20000,
        "ReceivedDate": "2023-06-12 16:05:39",
        "Currency": "BRL",
        "Country": "BRA",
        "Provider": "Simulado",
        "ReturnCode": "99",
        "ReturnMessage": "Timeout",
        "Status": 0,
        "Links": [
            {
                "Method": "GET",
                "Rel": "self",
                "Href": "https://apiquerysandbox.cieloecommerce.cielo.com.br/1/sales/48835b7d-e3af-45a2-9d85-2f7365415f5e"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

And the controller returns the following HTML file:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>

<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">

    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
        <title>Pessoa - Cadastro</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <h1>Dados enviados pelo usuário:</h1>

        <p>Código: <b th:text="${sale.getPayment().getReturnCode()}"/></p>
    </body>
</html>
```

So what I want is to get the returning Java POJO "sale" and display the content of the "ReturnCode" onscreen.

However the object that is sent to the View is from the parameter "sale", which has has it all as null, so it throws the following error:

`EL1011E: Method call: Attempted to call method getReturnCode() on null context object`

So how am I supposed to proceed from here?

Comment: Has the sale.payment.returnCode ever been set?

Comment: Yes, you see the line "sale = new CieloEcommerce(merchant, Environment.SANDBOX).createSale(sale);"? 

It returns the JSON object described above as a Java POJO, that's where the ReturnCode is found.

Answer (score 2):

I changed a little the your code controller because according to the documentation from https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/articles/springmvcaccessdata.html it is not quite correct the @ModelAttribute usage.
The controller is like:

```
@Controller
public class TestFrontend {

  @GetMapping(value = "/**")
  public String result( final Model model) {
    Sale sale = new Sale("ID do pagamento");
    Payment payment = new Payment("300");
    sale.setPayment(payment);
    model.addAttribute("sale",sale);
    return "index";
  }
}
```

And also the html I changed as below:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>

<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Pessoa - Cadastro</title>
</head>

<body>
<h1>Dados enviados pelo usuário:</h1>

<p>Código: <b th:text="${sale.payment.returnCode}"/></p>
</body>
</html>
```

Doing this changes I get printed the returnCode.

More about you can find https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/thymeleafspring.html#model-attributes

Comment: I shows a different error: EL1007E: Property or field 'returnCode' cannot be found on null

The problem, I think, is that in that code above there's a new object and payment being setup but both of the lack the information added in the PostController.

Comment: Did you tried the way I added it in the controller TestFrontend? I ran this with java 17, spring-boot 3.0.0, thymeleaf-spring6 (3.1.0.RELEASE). If you get that error I would say that the payment is not set to the sale.